# Justify content between spans

Tags: html, css, flexbox, justify

I'm trying to display a list of artists in a festival lineup format, taking advantage of the `:first-line` selector to display artists in the first line of the lineup as more prominent than the rest.

```css
.artists {
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.artists:first-line {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.artists span {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="artists">
  <span>Coldplay</span>
  <span>Nine Inch Nails</span>
  <span>Thom Yorke</span>
  <span>Solange</span>
  <span>Justice</span>
  <span>St. Vincent</span> ...
</div>
```

I want the list of artists to fill the width of the container, with spacing between each artist. The problem with the above implementation is that it's adding spacing both within and between artist names, as opposed to only adding spacing between artist names:

[image]

Is there a line of CSS that I could add to fix this? Is there an implementation with `display: inline-flex` and `justify-content: space-between` that could work? I could also get this working if I could add `display: inline-block` to the spans, but doing so gets rid of the `:first-line` styling.

Comment: Just one question...what will be if there are 3 or more than 3 lines? Festival lineup format can have it, and i guess that you want separation between multiple lines in that case, too... Your best bet would be some javascrpt, i guess, but...let's wait, maybe someone will have pure CSS solution...

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if there was a `:second-line` and `:third-line` selector as well, but I'm okay with just the one line styled differently (assuming I can get it working with CSS).

Comment: You will have to use a script here, and add e.g. a class to items in the first line. That will then also make it possible to distinct 2nd, 3rd, etc. line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this with CSS alone with the given markup and CSS is not possible.

If to be able to give each item a width, media query would be a possible solution, though a lot of hard coded CSS needed.

Here is a Flexbox/jQuery solution (and of course javascript can be used).

The tricky part here is that when one set a different font, it either will be space for more or less items, so when one change the font for row 2, the first item suddenly fit and will jump back up again.

So to make this work I here used the pseudo elements, to be able to create a *delimiter* between the 1st/2nd and 2nd/3rd line.

Also, one need to start with setting the biggest font size on all items, or else a similar issue occur, where when one change from an initial smaller, there suddenly is not space enough.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVewWq)

Stack snippet

```js
(function ($) {
  //  preload object array to gain performance
  var $items = $('.artists span'), 
      $cache = [];
    
  //  run at resize
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    $.fn.setItems(1);   
  });

  $.fn.setItems = function(idx) {

    // remove classes
    if ($cache && $cache.length > 0) {
      $items.removeClass(function(i, val) {
          return 'line' + $cache[i];
      });    
    }

    $cache = [];
    
    $items.each(function(i, obj) {    

      //  did top value changed
      if (i != 0 && $items.eq(i - 1).offset().top != $(obj).offset().top) {
        idx++;
      }
      
      $cache.push(idx);
    });
    
    //  set classes
    $items.addClass(function(i, val) {
        return 'line' + $cache[i];
    });    
  }
  
  //  run at load
  $.fn.setItems(1);

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.artists {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.artists::before, .artists::after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
}
.artists::after {
  order: 3;
}
.artists span {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.artists .line2 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  order: 2;
}
.artists .line3,
.artists .line3 ~ span {
  font-size: 1em;
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="artists">
  <span>Coldplay</span>
  <span>Nine Inch Nails</span>
  <span>Thom Yorke</span>
  <span>Solange</span>
  <span>Justice</span>
  <span>St. Vincent</span>
  
  <span>Coldplay 2</span>
  <span>Nine Inch Nails 2</span>
  <span>Thom Yorke 2</span>
  <span>Solange 2</span>
  <span>Justice 2</span>
  <span>St. Vincent 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.artists {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Hope, It works.